# How do I count unique visitors to my web page and recount the counter everyday without using database?

Tags: php

How do i count **unique visitors** to my web page using **php** and recount the counter everyday (24 h)?

Also, i need to save the number of visitors on text file. i don't need to use database.

This is what i try and its sample code to get user ip and count +1:

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$count = file_get_contents("counter.txt");
$count = trim($count);
$count = $count + 1;
$fl = fopen("counter.txt","w+");
fwrite($fl,$count);
fclose($fl);

echo $ip;

?>
```

Comment: You do need to use a database. The underlying storage method may be a text file, but it's still a database. Also, you'll need to store all the addresses you've seen so far so you know if the current one you're looking at has been seen before or not. You could possibly use a text file that's just a list of addresses seen so far which you search and append the current address if it's not found, but then how do you handle concurrent access? Also, REMOTE_ADDR is a poor way of checking for unique visitors, as it will undercount everyone behind a NATted interface.

Comment: @blm Thank you. I understand what you say but how i can do that with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    $filename = date("Ymd") . "_counter.txt";
    $seenFilename = date("Ymd") . '_seen_ip.txt';

    $ips = array();
    if (file_exists($seenFilename))
    {
        $ips = file($seenFilename);
        $ips = array_map('trim', $ips);
    }

    if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ips))
    {
        $visits = 0;
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            $visits = file_get_contents($filename);
        }


        file_put_contents($filename, ++$visits);
        $data = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
        $fp = fopen($seenFilename, 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $data);
    }

?>
```

This code will create a new file every day and record one count for each unique visit.

Comment: Thank for this best solution and i like the way but i try it and i think the counter doesn't work! i try with 3 different devices and it still 0 .

Comment: Let me look over it again

Comment: I found the error in the code and have corrected it, give it another go.

Comment: Great. It's working now. Thank you for your time and i hop the best for you. @dlporter98

Comment: I made an edit after my last comment, please be sure you get the code as it now stands.

Comment: @dlport98 I will. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know enough php, so maybe it "just works", but how does this handle concurrent access?

Comment: @dlporter98 How i can make this code to count unique visitors??

Comment: Our does count unique visits based on ip address. The seen ip file keeps a daily list of ip addresses it has seen and only counts the ip addresses it hasn't seen. New filled are created daily so that it tracks unique visits per day as you requested in you initial question.